# Is it possible disable a single radio button in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to disable a single radio button in a group using jquery?

```
<div id="divAddNewPayrollItemWages" title="Add New Payroll Item">
    <strong>Wages</strong><br />
    Do you want to set up a payroll item to track wages, annual salary, commissions or bonuses?<br />
    <input type="radio" name="rblWages" value="Hourly" />Hourly Wage<br />
    <input type="radio" name="rblWages" value="Annual" />Annual Salary<br />
    <input type="radio" name="rblWages" value="Commission" />Commission<br />
    <input type="radio" name="rblWages" value="Bonus" />Bonus<br /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Back" disabled="disabled" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="AddNewPayrollItemWages_Next();" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="Finish" disabled="disabled" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="AddNewPayrollItemWages_Cancel();" />
</div>
<div id="divAddNewPayrollItemHourlyWages" title="Add New Payroll Item">
    <strong>Wages</strong><br />
    Is this item for regular, overtime, sick or vacation pay?<br />
    <input type="radio" name="rblHourlyWages" value="Regular" />Regular Pay<br />
    <input type="radio" name="rblHourlyWages" value="Overtime" />Overtime Pay<br />
    <input type="radio" name="rblHourlyWages" value="Sick" />Sick Pay<br />
    <input type="radio" name="rblHourlyWages" value="Vacation Pay" />Vacation Pay<br /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="AddNewPayrollItemWages_Next();" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="Finish" disabled="disabled" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="AddNewPayrollItemHourlyWages_Cancel();" />
</div>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that when a user selects Annual from the first dialogue, the script opens the second dialogue and disables the Overtime radio button from the list. The only problem I am having at this point is disabling the radio button, everything else is good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it. Essentially, use jQuery to find an input with name of "rblHourlyWages" and value of "Overtime" and disable it.

```js
$('input[name=rblHourlyWages][value=Overtime]').prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="rblHourlyWages" value="Regular" />Regular Pay<br />
<input type="radio" name="rblHourlyWages" value="Overtime" />Overtime Pay<br />
<input type="radio" name="rblHourlyWages" value="Sick" />Sick Pay<br />
<input type="radio" name="rblHourlyWages" value="Vacation Pay" />Vacation Pay<br /><br />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not disable the radio button.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? You are *sure* that this code is executing?

Comment: jquery-2.1.3 and Ive placed a `debugger;` command in the mix to step through it, and it does hit the line but does not disable the button.

Comment: How strange. When you run the above code snippet does it disable? Does anything get returned in the console when you type `$('input[name=rblHourlyWages][value=Overtime]')`? Should get one element back. Also note that this will not look much different, the only thing that should happen is that the radio button cannot be clicked or otherwise changed.

Comment: I threw an alert in the mix as well to see what is actually being selected as follows: `alert($("input:radio[name=rblWages]").val().toLowerCase());` and the only thing it is returning (no matter what is selected) is hourly so it is definitely NOT hitting the disable code.

Comment: finally figured it out... I was using the wrong statement. Here is the correct statement that returns the correctly checked item: `$("input:radio[name='rblWages']:checked").val().toLowerCase()` and now it works.

Comment: @JohnSchultz shouldn't need to search the DOM again to find the radio value. You should already have access to element inside event handler

Comment: Sweet. Glad I could help. Be sure to check out the other two answers as well as they show a great way to interact with the callback.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is establish a relationship between what radio button disables another. I would use an array, but that's a whole other pie.

What you can do is something on the lines of checking the radio group and using an if statement.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("[type='radio']"), function(x) {
    x.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (x.value === "Annual") { //or any other field
            document.querySelector("['OTHER_RELATED_FIELD']").disabled = true;
        }
    });
});
```

jQuery way:

```
$("[type='radio']").on("click", function() {
    if (this.value === "Annual") $("[name='rblHourlyWages'][value='Overtime']").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Note that you'll have to reset all radio buttons to enabled before each click function is run so that you can change the radio button and the option will be re-enabled.

Comment: what if user changes first radio again?

Comment: Then you add a line to enable all fields, or a function, ran on each click to "restore" to original

Comment: Not a bug, just a feature the OP hasn't considered yet, thus, I didn't address. But I'll make a note

Comment: sure it's a bug if user can't undo it

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. It allows for user to change radio again and reenable the other one

```
$('[name=rblWages]').change(function(){
   var isAnnual = this.value == 'Annual';
    $('[name=rblHourlyWages][value=Overtime]').prop('disabled', isAnnual);
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ztfhchnr/)**</kbd>